# Multiple Authors with PDF/A and Adobe Acrobat DC

Tags: pdf, acrobat, pdfa

I'm trying to convert a document to PDF/A-3b using Adobe Acrobat DC 2015.016. However, every time I specify multiple authors - everyone beyond the first author gets truncated.

So I specify `John Doe; Jane Doe` - once I save it as PDF/A it ends up being just `John Doe` in the file details. I've tried without using conversion profiles - that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Can I bypass this? Should I use `"John Doe; Jane Doe"` - which apparently it accepts a one author.  I would like the authors to be correct.

Comment: I'm guessing the semicolon is the problem. Have you tried a comma? PDF/A requires that the XMP metadata conforms to the XMP specification, I think that's where it's getting hung up. XMP is XML and XML doesn't like semicolons unless they're escaped.

Comment: Awesome, hadn't thought about this somehow because the Keywords can have semicolons. Now it converts to `"John Doe, Jane Doe"`as two authors and the quotation marks are added automatically.. Nice. Would you copy and paste this as answer please?

Comment: Done. I was making an [educated] guess so I wasn't comfortable adding it as an answer but with your confirmation, I have. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a comma? PDF/A requires that the XMP metadata conforms to the XMP specification, I think that's where it's getting hung up. XMP is XML and XML doesn't like semicolons unless they're escaped. I'll bet that Acrobat doesn't try to escape the semicolons when it synchronizes the Document Information in the Properties dialog to the XMP.